# How to customize virtualbox configuration using docker-machine?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I am playing with `docker-machine` on my rough machine where I generally play with new things. I create a docker machine using the following command

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dockerinwild
```

and configure docker client to work with `dockerinwild` machine. Everything is working fine. But It takes all of my cpus and memory is low. How can I customize the virtualbox created by `docker-machine`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figure out how to customize it

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-cpu-count 2 --virtualbox-memory "4096" --virtualbox-disk-size "10000" dockerinwild
```

Official documentation with full list of virtualbox driver options :
https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/virtualbox/